# How can I access query parameters for the Health endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to pass a query parameter to the health endpoint. Is this possible?
For example, `http://localhost/health?id=asdfasdf`

I want to access the id in the health() method.

```
@Override
public Health health() {
   //access id here.
}
```

Thanks,

Jerry

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Mohammad, thank you for confirming this is possible but my question is how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Spring Boot endpoint is designed to be exposed to clients via a number of different techniques. For example both HTTP and JMX are supported out of the box. This means that using something that's HTTP-specific in an endpoint isn't a good idea.

That said, if you *really* want to provide a `HealthIndicator` that's HTTP-specific you should be able to use Spring's `RequestContextHolder` to get hold of a `ServletRequestAttributes` instance for the current request. From there you can access the `HttpServletRequest` and call `getQueryString()`:

```java
String queryString = (((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
            .getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getQueryString());
```

Comment: Thank you Andy! I'm trying it out now.